# How to play custom GUI sounds in GTK3 Python app?

Tags: python, audio, gtk3

Tinkering with a small GTK3 app in Python3, I can trigger XDG theme sounds like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version('GSound', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GSound

class PyApp:
  def __init__(self):
    super(PyApp, self).__init__()

    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file("test.glade")

    handlers = {
        "onButtonClick": self.onButtonClick
    }
    self.builder.connect_signals(handlers)

    self.sound = GSound.Context()
    self.sound.init()

    self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.window.show_all()

  def onButtonClick(self, button):
    self.sound.play_simple({ GSound.ATTR_EVENT_ID : "phone-incoming-call" })

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = PyApp()
  Gtk.main()
```

But how do I make GSound play my own sounds? Do I have to construct a custom XDG theme, and if so do I have to install this in the correct system folder (e.g. `/usr/share/sounds/`), or can I bundle it stand-alone with my app? Also, how do I tell the `Gsound.context()` which theme to use? Very little information available about this.

**Edit:** This looked promising:

```
self.sound = GSound.Context()
self.sound.set_attributes({GSound.ATTR_CANBERRA_XDG_THEME_NAME: "freedesktop"})
```

Alas:

```
gi.repository.GLib.Error: gsound - error - quark: Invalid argument (-2)
```

Comment: I've gone with `PyGame.mixer` for the GUI feedback sounds for now. Would still prefer to use libcanberra - after all _it's what it was built for_ - but it looks like the project was abandoned and left half finished (it's been nine years since the last release). Can't help noticing who the author is...